# Making decisions on expect return

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I am trying to create an expect script which will send a different password string based on the "expect"

- Condition A: If a cisco device has not been setup with a username then the first prompt will simply be "Password:" - then it should use passwordA (no username)
- Condition B: If it has been setup with a username then the prompt will be "Username:" followed by "Password:" - then it should use Username and PasswordB

```
#!/bin/bash
# Declare host variable as the input variable
host=$1　
 # Start the expect script
(expect -c "
set timeout 20
# Start the session with the input variable and the rest of the hostname
spawn telnet $host
set timeout 3 
if {expect \"Password:\"} {
send \"PasswordA\"}
elseif { expect \"Username:\"}
send \"UsersName\r\"}
expect \"Password:\"
log_user 0 
send \"PasswordB\r\"
log_user 1
expect \"*>\"
# send \"show version\r\"
# set results $expect_out(buffer) 
#expect \"Password:\"
#send \"SomeEnablePassword\r\"
# Allow us to interact with the switch ourselves
# stop the expect script once the telnet session is closed
send \"quit\r\"
expect eof
")
```

Comment: You'll make your code less mad if you use single-quotes to enclose the expect script itself, rather than double-quotes. Fewer backslashes required...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. :)

The `expect` statement doesn't look to see what comes first, it waits until it sees what you ask for (and times out if it doesn't arrive in time), and then runs a command you pass to it. I think you can use it something like the way you're trying to, but it's not good.

`expect` can take a list of alternatives to look for, like a C `switch` statement, or a shell `case` statement, and that's what you need here.

I've *not tested* this, but what you want should look something like this:

```
expect {
  -ex "Username:" {
    send "UsersName\r"
    expect -ex "Password:" {send "PasswordB\r"}
  }
  -ex "Password:" {send "PasswordA\r"}
}
```

In words, expect will look for either "Username:" or "Password:" (`-ex` means exact match, no regexp), whichever comes first, and run the command associated with it.

---

In response to the comments, I would try a second password like this (assuming that a successful login gives a '#' prompt):

```
expect {
  -ex "Username:" {
    send "UsersName\r"
    expect -ex "Password:" {send "PasswordB\r"}
  }
  -ex "Password:" {
    send "PasswordA1\r"
    expect {
      -ex "Password:" {send "PasswordA2\r"}
      -ex "#" {}
    }
  }
}
```

You *could* do it without looking for the `#` prompt, but you'd have to rely on the second `Password:` expect timing-out, which isn't ideal.

Comment: The other thing to know is that you can use `exp_continue` in a response body to make the containing `expect` keep waiting. That's useful for dealing with usernames/passwords, with the termination case being seeing the prompt on the target system…

Comment: Right, except that, in this case, `Password:` can mean two different things.

Comment: Thank you so much AMS! That worked!! I have recently found out that another password needs to be used in the case that the first password (without the username) doesn't work.

So the expect will be "Password:" send PasswordA
If the password fails then the same expect "Password:" will be returned then I should send PasswordB on the second instance

Comment: expect \"Username:\" {
                send \"USERNAME\r\"
                expect -ex \"Password:\" 
                 {send    \"PasswordWithUser    \!\r\"}
        }
         \"Password:\" {send \"PassNoUserA\r\"} 
    exp_continue 
         \"Password:\" {send \"PassNoUserB\r\"}

Comment: I added another example for that case. You *could* use `exp_continue` to do it as a loop, but it might go infinite, and you'd need a counter or something to choose which password to pass.