# Send <command>, expect with conditional testing?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have an `expect` script wrapped in a bash script for doing specific commands depending on whether an IP address is pulled from the Cisco router. The algorithm that I'm trying to code is something like the following:

```
send -h "ip int br"
expect -re {
    if "192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.{2}[0-9]{1,3}"
    {
        expect 
        {
            "up/up { do these things here }
            "down/down" { do this instead }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        send -h "<another command>"
        expect
        {
            "up/up" { do this }
            "down/down" { or this if down }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? I have tried using `expect`'s equivalent of the `switch` statements with the `-ex` flag as suggested in an answer to another user's question ([Making decisions on expect return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084870/making-decisions-on-expect-return)) but haven't had any result with that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would capture the returned address and then act on it. I see repeated code, so try to reduce that:

```
send -h "ip int br"
expect {
    timeout {error "can't find an ip address after 'ip int br' command"}
    -re {\m\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\M}
}
if { ! [regexp {192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.{2}[0-9]{1,3}} $expect_out(0,string)]} {
    send -h "<another command>"
}
expect {
    "up/up" { do these things here }
    "down/down" { do this instead }
}
```

Other notes:

- Take care in expect to put the opening brace of a block NOT on it's own line, but cuddled with the command.
- Put regular expressions in {braces} because this `"192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.{2}[0-9]{1,3}"` will give you an error like `invalid command name "0-9"` -- brackets are special to Tcl and need to be escaped unless they're in braces.

Comment: It's usually better to _specifically_ detect the prompt after the remote command finishes rather than relying on a timeout. But otherwise, looks pretty good.

Comment: Question: why is it that in the final expect block, my commands are run but not shown in my console window (terminal)? For testing I'm using reboot on "down/down", so `do this instead` looks like `{ reboot in 0:01; exit }`. Despite this command being registered by the router (in another terminal I am pinging the router and can see it drop a minute later as per the command), it is not being printed to my terminal as is `sh ip int br`. Why is this? Also: what is the best way to exit the script when using exit codes, i.e. do I still need `expect_eof` statement somewhere?

Comment: Try `expect eof` instead of `exit` after `send reboot`